# Get user info of asp.net core web app which authentificated with Azure AD(advanced)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, azure-active-directory

I have to authentificate my web app with azure AD(Advanced) on azure portal,now how can i get the user_id from /.auth/me to UI of web app

Comment: Can you add the code which you tried and challenges you are facing ?

Comment: Hi @ManojChoudhari. I set up the authentification to my web app with this docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) and than when user authentificate we can use api /.auth/me like this (www.example.com/.auth/me) which get to us user info(which  include user id) in json.How can i get the user_id to ui web app for example to navbar with c#(razor).

Comment: List<Adto> ab = as.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a->a.week, Collectors.toList()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(es->{
       Adto adto = new Adto();
       adto.week = es.getKey();
       adto.aSubDTO = es.getValue().stream()
          .map(a->{
            AsubDTO asubDTO = new AsubDTO();
            asubDTO.title = a.title;
            asubDTO.day = a.day;
            return asubDTO;
          })
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
       return adto;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: lots of thanks @K.Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

In Angular8:

```
this.http.get<any>
("https://{{NAME_OF_YOUR_AZURE_WEB_APP}}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me").subscribe(res => userInfo = res[0].user_id);
```

Comment: thanks i solved it with ajax request, your code seems like works.